# using implode to insert values into database table columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am using php implode to insert values, fetched from array of input fields, into a database table column. This works fine for me:

```
$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (Ideal) VALUES (" . implode('),(', $_POST["ideal"]) . ")");
```

I'd like to now insert values, fetched from two different array of input fields, into two database table columns. The below code produces and error:

```
$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (AID,Ideal) VALUES (" . implode('),(', $_POST["act"]) . " ," . implode('),(', $_POST["ideal"]) . ")");
```

i'd like to express the two arrays, in the insert statement, as, e.g: (10,21),(20,31),(30,41)  and not (10),(21),(20),(31),(30),(41)

any idea on how to go about this, is highly appreciated.

Comment: What error does it produce? What is the contents of $_POST? As shown you are vulnerable to SQL injection using submitted values directly in your query.

Comment: it prodices the error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this it may help you

```
$ideal=implode('),(', $_POST["ideal"]);
$act=implode('),(', $_POST["act"]);

$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (Ideal) VALUES (" .mysql_real_escape_string($ideal). ")");
$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (AID,Ideal) VALUES (" .mysql_real_escape_string($ideal). " ," .mysql_real_escape_string($act). ")");
```

and try to use `mysqli` insted of `mysql`.

In `mysqli`

```
$insert_row = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (Ideal) VALUES ($ideal)");
$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (AID,Ideal) VALUES ($ideal,$act)");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this query with your query its work you

```
$insert_row =mysql_query("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (AID,Ideal) VALUES ( '". implode('),(', $_POST["act"]). "' ,'" .implode('),(', $_POST["act"])."')");
```

Comment: It works, but only stores one row of records, instead of many rows of records. When i echo the two arrays, according to your code; $Ideal = implode('),(', $_POST["ideal"]);
$act = implode('),(', $_POST["act"]);   ECHO " '$Ideal,$act'";  this' the results i get: 1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1,19),(18),(17),(16),(15),(14
                                                  
NB:// only (1,19) is stored

Comment: Not getting you...please edit your question with what you getting and what you want. thanks @Kenn

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the mysql_query extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Since a MySQLi example has been given consider if you were to use PDO.

```
// Build the parameter list
$sql = array(); $params = array();
for ($i=0; isset($_POST['ideal'][$i])&&isset($_POST['act'][$i]); $i++) {
    $sql[] = ":act_{$i}, :ideal_{$i}";

    $params["ideal_{$i}"] = $_POST['ideal'][$i];
    $params["act_{$i}"] = $_POST['act'][$i];
}

// Then run the query safely using PDO
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "user", "pass");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ActivityProduct (AID, Ideal) VALUES (".implode("), (", $sql).")");
$result = $stmt->execute($params);
```